# SQL subquery Access - one before last

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hopefully someone can help me with this query I want to make in Access. I have a table with three columns and a value column. It concerns financial data of which more than one version is there, so for B2C / SI_01 / INP01 I have for example four versions with different timestamps. How can I by means of a sub query, query the "before last" timestamp of the combinations of B2C / SI_01 / INP01? I tried it a couple of times with top n-2, descending sort order and not like max time stamp but I seem not to get the sql correct.

[image]

So far I my code is:

```
SELECT  [N-1], SI_Initiative, LineCode, Timestamp
FROM TBL_VC_DATA t1
WHERE t1.Timestamp = 
    (SELECT Max(t2.Timestamp) 
     FROM TBL_VC_DATA t2
     WHERE t2.timestamp<>t1.timestamp
     AND t2.[N-1]=t1.[N-1]
     AND t2.SI_Initiative=t1.SI_Initiative
     AND t2.LineCode=t1.LineCode);
```

Thanks in advance,

Michiel

Comment: Is it guaranteed, in the way your database gets populated with data, that you will never have the same timestamp on more than one record with the same N1, Initiative and LineCode?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `TOP 2` in your query, sorted descending by the timestamp, and then exclude the max (last) timestamp record.

```
SELECT TOP 2 [N-1], SI_Initiative, LineCode, Timestamp
FROM TBL_VC_DATA t1
WHERE t1.Timestamp <> (SELECT MAX(t2.Timestamp)
                       FROM TBL_VC_DATA t2
                       WHERE t2.timestamp <> t1.timestamp AND
                             t2.[N-1] = t1.[N-1] AND
                             t2.SI_Initiative = t1.SI_Initiative AND
                             t2.LineCode = t1.LineCode)
ORDER BY t1.Timestamp DESC
```

Your addition in the subquery's `WHERE` clause of `WHERE t2.timestamp <> t1.timestamp` is good, because it will allow the above query to return *both* records should there be a time between the last and second-to-last record with regard to timestamp value.